# Two errors showing up in code

Tags: swift

This is my code this shows an error here. What can I do about this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var laps: String = String() // just written the thing above bcz SO was complaining

var timer = Timer()
var minutes: Int = 0
var seconds: Int = 0
var fractions: Int = 0
var startstopwatch = true
var addLap = false
var stopWatchString: String = ""

@IBOutlet var stopWatchLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var lapsTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var startsTopButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func startstop(_ sender: Any) {

    if startstopwatch == true{
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateStopWatch), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startstopwatch = false
        startsTopButton.setTitle("Stop", for: UIControlState.normal)
        lapresetBtn.setTitle("Lap", for: UIControlState.normal)
        addLap = true
    }else {
        timer.invalidate()
        startstopwatch = true
        startsTopButton.setTitle("Start", for: UIControlState.normal)
        lapresetBtn.setTitle("Reset", for: .normal)
        addLap = false
    }
}

@IBOutlet var lapresetBtn: UIButton!

@IBAction func lapreset(_ sender: Any) {

    if addLap == true {

        laps.insert("\(stopWatchString)", at: 0)
        lapsTableView.reloadData()

    }else {
        addLap = false
        lapresetBtn.setTitle("Lap", for: .normal)
        fractions = 0
        seconds = 0
        minutes = 0

        stopWatchString = "00:00.00"
        stopWatchLabel.text = stopWatchString
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    stopWatchLabel.text = "00:00.00"
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func updateStopWatch(){
    fractions += 1
    if fractions == 100{
        seconds += 1
        fractions = 0
    }
    if seconds == 60{
        minutes += 1
        seconds = 0
    }
    let fractionsString = fractions > 9 ? "\(fractions)" : "0\(fractions)"
    let secondsString = seconds > 9 ? "\(seconds)" : "0\(seconds)"
    let minuteString = minutes > 9 ? "\(minutes)" : "0\(minutes)"
    stopWatchString = "\(minuteString):\(secondsString).\(fractionsString)"
    stopWatchLabel.text = stopWatchString

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Lap  \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = laps[indexPath.row + 1]//Subscript is unavailable. there is no universally good reason check documentation for more details

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return laps.count // count is unavailable. there is no universally good reason. check documentation for more details


}
```

Comment: You probably meant for `laps` to be a `[String]`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make laps an Array of Strings (line 3):

```
var laps = [String]()
```

Then, your errors are solved.

**1.** ***"Count is unavailable"*** was thrown because laps was a `String`, not an array of strings, and String has no `.count` property, it has `.characters.count`

**2.** ***"Subscript is unavailable"*** was thrown just for the same reason, because non-array / non-dictionary / non-collection types do no have subscripts (i.e.: `[indexPath.row + 1]`), and `String` is one of them.

Hope it helps!